# Angular: Access this.id declared in an "OnInit" function

Tags: javascript, angular, class, parameters, angular-ui-router

## Update 1

After I read Alexanders suggestions, I updated the code and got no error back. But Angular doesn't do a request to the server anymore, which make me curious. And also the `pageTitle` does not update.

#### appointmentDetail.component.html

```
{{appointmentDetail.time}}
```

#### appointmentDetail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APIService } from './../../../api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointmentdetail',
  templateUrl: './appointmentDetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointmentDetail.component.scss']
})
export class AppointmentDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  id: any;
  appointmentDetail$: Observable<Object>; // I'd really create an interface for appointment or whatever instead of  object or any
  pageTitle = 'Some Default Title Maybe';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private title: Title,
    private apiService: APIService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appointmentDetail$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      tap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.id = params.get('id');
        // Or this.id = +params.get('id'); to coerce to number maybe
        this.pageTitle = 'Termin' + this.id;
        this.title.setTitle(this.pageTitle);
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.apiService.getAppointmentDetailsById(this.id))
    );
  }
  public getData() {
    this.apiService
      .getAppointmentDetailsById(this.id)
      .subscribe((data: Observable<Object>) => {
        this.appointmentDetail$ = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

#### api.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class APIService {
  API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  getAppointments() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL}/appointments/`);
  }
  getAppointmentDetailsById(id) {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL}/appointments/${id}`);
  }
  getAppointmentsByUser(email) {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL}/user/${email}/appointments`);
  }
  getCertificatesByUser(email) {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL}/user/${email}/certificates`);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I want to grab that parameter `id` from the router parameters and want to pass it into my API call, which will do a Angular HTTP request. Hope I'm right, haha.

---

## Original Question

Currently, I ran into a nasty problem. The thing is, I want to read the params, which are given to me by `ActivatedRouter` and the Angular `OnInit` function. I subscribe them params and log them in the console. Until here, everything is working fine. But I want to access "`this.id`" outside from my `OnInit` function, so I can use it on pageTitle for example.

But, this.id is undefined. So the page title is Termineundefined.

Source code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APIService } from './../../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment-details',
  templateUrl: './appointment-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment-details.component.scss']
})
@Injectable()
export class AppointmentDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private routeSub: any;
  id: any;
  private appointmentDetail: Array<object> = [];
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private title: Title,
    private apiService: APIService
  ) {}

  pageTitle = 'Termin' + this.id;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title.setTitle(this.pageTitle);
    this.getData();

    this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
      this.id = params['id'];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  public getData() {
    this.apiService
      .getAppointmentDetailsById(this.id)
      .subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
        this.appointmentDetail = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Are you not able to see the `id` on the DOM by using the string interpolation syntax(`{{id}}`)

Comment: this.id is undefined. So the page title is Termineundefined.

Comment: What is the URL that you can see in the Address Bar?

Comment: Don't set `pageTitle` etc until inside the `subscribe` function

Comment: Please add your template code as well.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera This is my url, dynamic routing: "http://localhost:4200/termin/details/173280212"

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera There is no template code at all, except an "it works", because pageTitle is already undefined.

Comment: If possible, please create a StackBlitz project that replicates this issue. I'm pretty sure there's some issue with the syntax that you might have used.

Comment: By template code, I was referring to code that you might have in `appointment-details.component.html`

Comment: @dmnktoe You can't set the values until you've set `this.id`, so you'll need to wait until `this.id` has been set

Comment: @user184994 But I thougt it has been set? Because `this.id = params['id']`...

Comment: @dmnktoe It is asynchronous, so that is only done once `subscribe` is called. For that reason, you also need to set `pageTitle = 'Termin' + this.id;` inside the subscribe, and then call `this.title.setTitle(this.pageTitle);`

Comment: The official router documentation has an exact example of using switchMap RxJS operator to effectively await resolution/emit of route params for use downstream including http calls and more. You'd need to use RxJS operators to ensure that value is available prior to setting title or anything else really. Check out the router documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here really comes down to async availability of route params and observable streams. You simply cannot use the value until it has resolved for all practical purposes. You can use RxJS operators such as `switchMap` and `tap` in line with the official [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action) documentation to ensure route param `id` is available prior to use. `tap` can be used to introduce side effects such as setting class `id` property from route params and/or setting title. You could even create a class property of an `Observable<YourObject[]>` and utilize Angular Async Pipe to avoid subscribing and unsubscribing to display the data.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APIService, MyFancyInterface } from './../../api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment-details',
  templateUrl: './appointment-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment-details.component.scss']
})
export class AppointmentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  id: any;
  appointmentDetail$: Observable<MyFancyInterface>;
  appointmentDetail: MyFancyInterface;
  pageTitle = 'Some Default Title Maybe';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private title: Title,
    private apiService: APIService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appointmentDetail$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      tap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.id = params.get('id')
        // Or this.id = +params.get('id'); to coerce to type number maybe
        this.pageTitle = 'Termin' + this.id;
        this.title.setTitle(this.pageTitle);
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.apiService.getAppointmentDetailsById(this.id))
    );

    /* Or
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      tap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.id = params.get('id')
        // Or this.id = +params.get('id'); to coerce to type number maybe
        this.pageTitle = 'Termin' + this.id;
        this.title.setTitle(this.pageTitle);
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.apiService.getAppointmentDetailsById(this.id))
    ).subscribe((data: MyFancyInterface) => {
      this.appointmentDetail = data;
    });
    */
  }

}
```

Template:

```
<div>{{(appointmentDetail | async)?.id}}</div>
```

I'd recommend to create an interface to represent your data model and type the return of your api service method:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// maybe put this into another file
export interface MyFancyInterface {
  id: number;
  someProperty: string;
  ...
}

export class APIService {
  ...
  getAppointmentDetailsById(id): Observable<MyFancyInterface> {
    return this.httpClient.get<MyFancyInterface>(`${this.API_URL}/appointments/${id}`);
  }
  ...
}
```

If you really must, you can save the observable as you do now for the route params and subscribe as needed in the various parts of the class, but this demonstrated way you almost absolutely know that route param `id` will be available for use and can explicitly set the things you need to set.

I'd also remove `@Injectable()` as there is no reason to have it here with a `@Component()` decorator.

**Note*** the async pipe operator in this example ensures the Http call is executed. Otherwise a subscribe() is needed (search SO for Angular http not executing to see similar issues)

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate! But this doesn't work as I'm getting this error: `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.`

Comment: Well, in your question you assigned `data` in `subscribe()` to type/variable `private appointmentDetail: Array<object> = [];`. I therefore assumed the api service method/call was returned some sort of array `[]`. This error message indicates you are mixing up types object vs array. Does your service return an array or a single object? Either way, the RxJS approach will ensure your route params are available prior to use in setting title or making the api call. Just change the type of the class property and/or service method to match what you need. Thanks!

Comment: If your service method is returning an object just change this component&amp;#39;s class property signature to Observable&amp;lt;object&amp;gt; and update the template to not use ngFor. Without seeing your template or signature of API service it's hard to guess/assume the types/uses. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I implemented your code properly and got no errors back anymore, but Angular doesn't do a request anymore. I updated my original entry for a more detailed view.

Comment: You need to either use async pipe in the template or explicitly call subscribe() to make the call happen. Also I'd recommend adding typed returns to your API methods such Observable<any[]>. Thanks!

Comment: Things won't get work. :( FYI, my server response is an json object - no array. But I ask myself, why the pageTitle doesn't get updated...

Comment: I've updated to reflect a return type for the API service's call as well as the components types. To get an HttpClient call to actually execute you need to either use the `async` pipe in the template or `subscribe()` to the observable class property.

Comment: I had to remove the `async` pipe to get it working. Many thanks Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`id: any;`

You could try using a getter, like so

```
public get id(): any {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    return params['id'];
   }
}
```

In your template, just

```
{{ id }}
```

Comment: Usually you would `return` something with a getter function. Have you actually tried this with an `Observable` or `Promise`?